# Swift NSMutableData append Byte

Tags: swift

I'm trying to append one byte to an NSMutable data variable in swift and I'm looking for an easier way.  The relevant objective-c code would be:

```
NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
uint8_t number = 255;
[data appendBytes:&number length:2];
```

I haven't found that I can do something similar in Swift.  What does work is to first create an  array of Byte values and then pass that in.  For example:

```
    var data = NSMutableData()
    let value: Byte = 0xFF
    let byte: [Byte] = [value]
    data.appendBytes(byte, length: 1)

    //this works too and is a little simpler
    data.appendBytes([value] as [Byte], length: 1)
```

Is there a simpler way or am I missing something?  The doc specifies that it needs an UnsafePointer and an UnsafePointer can be created with a Word (typealias for Int), so the following works

```
    var word: Word = 255
    data.appendBytes(UnsafePointer(bitPattern: word), length: 4)
```

But that's not really what I want - I want a Byte (UInt8).  Any suggestions?

Comment: Length should be "1" in your ObjC code example :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html), when a function is declared as taking a UnsafePointer argument, it can accept any of the following:

- nil, which is passed as a null pointer
- An UnsafePointer, UnsafeMutablePointer, or AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer value, which is converted to UnsafePointer if necessary
- An in-out expression whose operand is an lvalue of type Type, which is passed as the address of the lvalue
- A [Type] value, which is passed as a pointer to the start of the array, and lifetime-extended for the duration of the call

The third bullet means you can do:

```
var value: Byte = 0xFF    // must be var, let will not work
data.appendBytes(&value, length: 1)
```

Note:  You must use `var` here and not `let` because it must be an lvalue.

If you find yourself adding a single byte frequently, you could extend `NSMutableData`:

```
extension NSMutableData {
    func appendByte(var b: Byte) {
        self.appendBytes(&b, length: 1)
    }
}

var data = NSMutableData()
data.appendByte(255)
```

Edit (Swift 3):

```
extension NSMutableData {
  func appendByte(_ i: Int8) {
    var i = i
    self.append(&i, length: 1)
  }
}

var data = NSMutableData()
data.appendByte(255)
```

Comment: Thanks, the key part that I was missing was to use var and not let to declare the Byte.

Comment: For compatibility with newer (and future) versions of switch, I modified the extension thusly:
```
extension NSMutableData {
    func appendByte(b: UInt8) {
        var newByte = b
        self.appendBytes(&newByte, length: 1)
    }
}
```